# Pasar objeto de javascript a java

Tags: javascript, java, script

Tengo una clase llamada temp que se encarga de obtener los valores de javascript

```
class temp{
   public void p(Object g){
       Class h = g.getClass();
       Method f = h.getDeclaredMethod("success");
        f.invoke(null);
   }
}
```

El método Main

```
public class frame{
    public static void Main(String[] ARG){
        
      ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
       ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
       engine.put("temp", new temp());
      
       engine.put("console",System.out);

       engine.eval("temp.p({success: funtion(){ console.print('load');}})");
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo me da error, Dice que no existe el metodo success.

¿como paso un objeto de javascript a Java y ejecutar las funciones del objeto?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento no se da como lo espera por las siguientes circunstancias:

1. El tipo de dato que llega en el parametro `g` del metodo `p` de su clase `temp` no es un objeto de java con los métodos que declara en javascript, sino una instancia de `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror` que es una clase envolvente; dicha clase no tiene un método `success`, pero provee un método `callMember` con el cual se pueden invocar los miembros del objeto javascript subyacente.
2. Para que los metodos sean visibles dentro del `ScriptEngine`  la clase `temp` y los métodos deberían ser publicos.
3. Si se conocen los nombres de los miembros del objeto de javascript, no es necesario utilizar reflexion de clases y metodos

La solucion que propongo es una clase `JsObjectWrapper` que envuelve el script subyacente en un objeto de javas a traves del cual se invocan los miembros del objeto Javascript, pero desde el runtime de java

Se necesitan dos archivos de clases para ilustrar el funcionamiento:

`JsObjectWrapper.java`

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

public class JsObjectWrapper {
    private ScriptObjectMirror _som;
    
    //Inicializa el objeto Java envolvente con el script del objeto Javascript
    public void init(Object obj) {
        this._som = (ScriptObjectMirror)obj;
    }
    
    //Invoca el metodo success1 de del objeto javascript subyacente
    public void callSuccess1() {
        this._som.callMember("success1");
    }
    
    //Invoca el metodo success2 de del objeto javascript subyacente
    public void callSuccess2() {
        this._som.callMember("success2");
    }    

    //Invocacion generica
    public void callMember(String memberName) {
        this._som.callMember(memberName);
    }
}
```

`Main.java`

```
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        
        //Inyecta la consola de salida de java como clave con nombre "console" en el motor de script
        engine.put("console",System.out);
        
        //Crea una instancia de JsObjectWrapper y la incluye como una clave con nombre jsow1
        JsObjectWrapper jsow1 = new JsObjectWrapper();
        engine.put("jsow1", jsow1);
        //Inicializa la instancia jsow1 con el script de objeto javascript
        engine.eval("jsow1.init({success1:function(){console.print('success(1)\\n')},success2:function(){console.print('success(2)\\n')}})");
        
        //Invoca a traves de la instancia de JsObjectWrapper los miembros success1 y success2
        jsow1.callSuccess1();
        jsow1.callSuccess2();
        
        //Usando la invocacion generica
        jsow1.callMember("success1");

        System.out.print("FIN");        
    }
}
```